# Android getHeight returns a wrong value

Tags: android, size, screen

I've got a class where i draw some line with canvas. In this class i want to use the height and the width of the screen. But there is a problem. I have a device with a scren 480x800. But when i call the function getWidth() and getHeight() so:

```
height = getHeight();
width = getWidth();
```

The width is correct because the width value is 480. But the height value is 483, and should be 800. Does anyone know why?

Comment: You're calling the getHeight() method on a view within the Parent...

Comment: Sorry I'm not very experienced in programming for Android, what should I do?

Comment: One way: getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels - but, not the ideal way!

Comment: That won't work, though. Your Canvas is sized 480x483, you need to make your view cover the whole screen instead.

Answer (score 0):

when you use `getHeight();` in your view it give you height of your view no height of screen .see this link [Get screen dimensions in pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/how-to-get-screen-dimensions)